# How to restore many providers from session?

Tags: php, mysql, session, restore, hybridauth

I have user in database, with registered many providers and with saved sessions in MySQL. I need to use getAdapter() on many providers, to restore this sessions. But it does not work. Hybridauth does not restore all providers.

But when I use authenticate() insted of getAdapter(), then autenthicate() do his job. But I need to use gedAdapter, becouse it is more quick.

```
$config = dirname(__FILE__) . '/library/hybridauth.php';
require_once( "library/Hybrid/Auth.php" );
$hybridauth = new Hybrid_Auth( $config );

$current_user_id = $_COOKIE['user_id'];
$registered_providers = getRegisteredProviders(); // [Facebook => 1234567896, Twitter => 1234567, Google => 123456789]
$hybridauth_session_data = get_stored_hybridauth_session( $current_user_id );

$hybridauth->restoreSessionData( $hybridauth_session_data );

foreach ($registered_providers as $provider => $provider_id) {
   try{
       $adapter = $hybridauth->getAdapter( $provider );
       $user_profile = $adapter->getUserProfile();
       echo = $user_profile->identifier;
   }
   catch( Exception $e ){
       echo "Ooophs, we got an error: " . $e->getMessage();
   }
}
```